# Is there a word that describes an over exaggeration due to one being sheltered by wealth/an elite social class?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For instance, wealthy people complaining wind turbines ruin their view and disrupt their lives when an average person would find simply having a view of the ocean pleasurable? I hope this gets the point across. 
I want to say "pedantic" but I don't think it quite fits.

What is the term for this situation?

Comment: Their fine sensibilities are offended.

Comment: We need at least two words, I think, with one of them being *naive* or *naivete*.  Or *innocent* or *innocence*.  I'm thinking of the wonderful song by the incomparable Violeta Parra, "Porque los pobres no tienen".  There's a verse where she talks about the brainwashed, innocent poor who "**in their innocence**" believe that they will go to hell if they pursue revolution.  *"De tiempos inmemoriales
que se ha inventa’o el infierno
para asustar a los pobres
con sus castigos eternos,
y al pobre, que es inocente,
con su inocencia creyendo."*

Comment: Snobbish, maybe?

Comment: Your example doesn't really work because a lot of "average" people would complain about the wind turbines, and some wealthy people might not mind them.

Answer (score 1):

**[Privileged](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/privileged)** [MW]

> having special rights or advantages that most people do not have